# ftp does not transfer complete file

Tags: python, ftp

I have the following code to transfer a file to another linux machine:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('192.168.1.111','ubuntu','ubuntu')
file = open('/home/nehal/darknet/yolo.weights','rb')                  # file to send
print(session.pwd())
print(ftplib.FTP.dir(session))
session.storbinary('STOR /home/ubuntu/yolo.weights',file)                  #send the file
file.close()
session.quit()
```

The file `yolo.weights` is of 209MB and only few MBs are transferred.

I also tried transferring a file of 30MB but only a few MBs get transferred and it seems like no data is transferred thereafter.
**What could be the issue?**

Comment: Try removing the path from the `STOR`. You could try `session.cwd('/home/ubuntu')` then just `STOR yolo.weights`

Comment: @MartinEvans it worked! Thank you! Please post this as an answer What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `STOR` you should pass only the filename and not the path. So to ensure the file ends up in the correct place, use `.cwd()` to first specify the target directory:

```
import ftplib

session = ftplib.FTP('192.168.1.111','ubuntu','ubuntu')
file = open('/home/nehal/darknet/yolo.weights','rb')                  # file to send
print(session.pwd())
print(ftplib.FTP.dir(session))

session.cwd('/home/ubunto')
session.storbinary('STOR yolo.weights',file)                  #send the file

file.close()
session.quit()
```

Or you could try as follows:

```
import ftplib

session = ftplib.FTP('192.168.1.111', 'ubuntu', 'ubuntu')
file = open('/home/nehal/darknet/yolo.weights', 'rb')

with session, file:
    print(session.pwd())
    print(ftplib.FTP.dir(session))
    session.cwd('/home/ubunto')
    session.storbinary('STOR yolo.weights', file)
```

Comment: Why does ftp not work when the whole path is specified?

Comment: AFAIK it is part of the protocol specification. You are just giving it the filename to use for the current directory.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Comment: @MartinEvans While you are right and I'd understand if the server did reject the `STOR` command straight away, I do not get why the transfer actually happens, but aborts after few MBs.